# Cisco 3850 All ports turns amber when SFP inserted

Tags: networking, cisco, switch

We have replaced old 3750 switches with WS-C3850-24T (Qty:2 in stack mode). Whenever I insert any SFP module to connect our different depts, all ports turns amber for few seconds, during this phase all connectivity of other ports disconnects , and after few seconds all ports runs back to green and connectivity restores. This never happened in old 3750 switches. What could be the possible cause?

Following is STP details.

```
xxx-NOC-3850-Cluster#show spanning-tree summary
Switch is in rapid-pvst mode
Root bridge for: none
Extended system ID           is enabled
Portfast Default             is disabled
PortFast BPDU Guard Default  is disabled
Portfast BPDU Filter Default is disabled
Loopguard Default            is disabled
EtherChannel misconfig guard is enabled
UplinkFast                   is disabled
BackboneFast                 is disabled
Configured Pathcost method used is short

Name                   Blocking Listening Learning Forwarding STP Active
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
VLAN0001                     0         0        0         28         28
---------------------- -------- --------- -------- ---------- ----------
1 vlan                       0         0        0         28         28
```

Following is Inventory output:

```
    XXX-NOC-3850-Cluster#sh inv

NAME: "c38xx Stack", DESCR: "c38xx Stack"
PID: WS-C3850-24T     , VID: V07 , SN: FOC2126L0T1

NAME: "Switch 1", DESCR: "WS-C3850-24T-S"
PID: WS-C3850-24T-S   , VID: V07 , SN: FOC2126L0T1

NAME: "StackPort1/1", DESCR: "StackPort1/1"
PID: STACK-T1-50CM   , VID: V01 , SN: MOC2102A2VN

NAME: "Switch 1 - Power Supply B", DESCR: "Switch 1 - Power Supply B"
PID: PWR-C1-350WAC   , VID: V02 , SN: LIT20462TNP

NAME: "Switch 1 FRU Uplink Module 1", DESCR: "4x1G Uplink Module"
PID: C3850-NM-4-1G   , VID: V01 , SN: FOC21083GDN

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/1/1", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                   , VID:     , SN: FNS12060A5K

NAME: "GigabitEthernet1/1/4", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                   , VID:     , SN: FNS17041183

NAME: "Switch 2", DESCR: "WS-C3850-24T-S"
PID: WS-C3850-24T-S   , VID: V07 , SN: FCW2113C1AK

NAME: "StackPort2/1", DESCR: "StackPort2/1"
PID: STACK-T1-50CM   , VID: V01 , SN: MOC2102A2VN

NAME: "Switch 2 - Power Supply B", DESCR: "Switch 2 - Power Supply B"
PID: PWR-C1-350WAC   , VID: V02 , SN: ART2205FCLN

NAME: "Switch 2 FRU Uplink Module 1", DESCR: "4x1G Uplink Module"
PID: C3850-NM-4-1G   , VID: V01 , SN: FOC21065HC4

NAME: "GigabitEthernet2/1/1", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                   , VID:     , SN: FNS17041321

NAME: "GigabitEthernet2/1/4", DESCR: "1000BaseSX SFP"
PID:                   , VID:     , SN: FNS17041205
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user ports aren't in portfast mode (either by default as shown by `Portfast Default is disabled`, or per port) then as spanning-tree converges you will have outages.

User ports are recommended to be set as follows to minimize STP impact:

```
switchport mode access
switchport access vlan ###
spanning-tree portfast
```

If you don't want to type `spanning-tree portfast` on each interface, then you can set all access ports to portfast mode with `spanning-tree portfast default` in global configuration mode.

Also using Vlan 1 is not recommended because it's usually untagged and used by Cisco for network admin functions that are worth separating from user traffic.

Comment: Actually, it can get to be a real pain for switches where ports may change roles. Cisco allows you to globally configure portfast and bpduguard, and it only affects access interfaces if you do not use the `trunk` keyword. That way, if you change an access interface to a trunk interface, or vice versa, you do not need to remember to change it on the interface configuration. Globally configure `spanning-tree portfast default` and `spanning-tree portfast bpduguard default`.

Comment: Thank you , spanning tree ports fast resolved it. Thx again